# What tool should I use to animate text on an EXTREMELY high resolution "screen"?

Tags: video, video-editor, animation-rendering

I need to make a video with extrodinary dimensions.

The "screen" will have to be large enough to hold a very large amount of text and diagrams....  say 20,000 By 20,000 pixels.  The text is going to be transitioned onto the "screen" one word at a time - synchronized with a voice over.

I'm then going to take this animation and wrap it around a sphere in Maya and have a "camera" follow the text/diagrams as they are revealed (with a big finish where the camera zooms out and shows the text has formed word clouds in the shape of continents).

Can someone suggest a tool or method I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After effects, and while your at it, just do the whole thing in After effects, by the time this renders out, and then bring it into maya, apply camera animation, and render it out, you could have made 20 with AE

Comment: After Effects was a good solution; it does let one produce an animation of extrodinary dimensions - and of course it's text effects are second to none.  However Maya was necessary, even if it's ardious, as After Effects can't do the camera/sphere part of the animation.